# How do I restrict users from being able to create ANY flows?

Tags: visual-workflow, permissions

We want to restrict the ability of users to create flows in our production org -  ANY flows.  How can I do this with the current permissions?  We have some issues with admins and other super users creating flows sometimes in our production org.
Thanks in advance.

Wayne

Answer (score 0):

To restrict access to prevent users from editing or creating flows, you'll have to clone a profile, and unchecked the **manage flow** under general user permissions section of that profile. So for example, if you want to have a system admin with several capabilities of an admin except for creating a flow and editing one, you could clone the system admin profile and unchecked manage flow. Users will still be able to see the flow but they will not be able to edit, create, or run new flows. You can also grant permission sets to users to allow access to edit and run flows by checking the manage flow checkbox. You cannot restrict access with permission sets and profiles.

Comment: Where is the general user permissions sections-  do you mean system permissions?  Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Sure! It would be under their profile. Here is the reference: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.retail_task_admin_permission_flow.htm&type=5